# Only want to consider a dataframe up to the present point

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I am trying to do something along the lines of

```
df['foo'] = np.where(myfunc(df) == 1, 10, 20)
```

but I only want to consider the dataframe up to the present, for example if my dataframe looked like

```
     A    B    C
1  0.3  0.3  1.6
2  0.6  0.6  0.4
3  0.9  0.9  1.2
4  1.2  1.2  0.8
```

and I was generating the value of 'foo' for the third row, I would be looking at the dataframe's first through third rows, but not the fourth row. Is it possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible. The dataframe up to the present is given by

```
df.iloc[:present],
```

and you can do whatever you want with it, in particular, use `where`, as described here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html

Comment: 'present' does not seem to be defined for use in iloc and raises an error when I try to use it

Comment: @camphor `present` was just a placeholder for whatever the value you wanted. Jeez.